# Illegal rook move?

Tags: discussion

While typing out a replayer example game for [What are the most possible total pawn captures for a game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/38974/what-are-the-most-possible-total-pawn-captures-for-a-game), I came across the following rook move that is seemingly not allowed, 14. Rc6

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nd5 Nd4 4. Ne5 Ne4 5. Nb6 Nb3 6. Ng6 Ng3 7. axb3 axb6 8. hxg3 hxg6 9. Ra4 Rh5 10. Rf4 Rc5 11. Rf6 Rc3 12. Rh4 Ra5 13. Rc4 Rf5 14. Rc6
```

But moving it one square shorter seems to be allowed

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nd5 Nd4 4. Ne5 Ne4 5. Nb6 Nb3 6. Ng6 Ng3 7. axb3 axb6 8. hxg3 hxg6 9. Ra4 Rh5 10. Rf4 Rc5 11. Rf6 Rc3 12. Rh4 Ra5 13. Rc4 Rf5 14. Rc5
```

I can't manage to figure out why moving the rook to c6 is not allowed.

- It's white's turn
- A white rook is standing on c4, no piece is on c5 or c6.
- Neither king is in check, or gets checked by the move.
- Castling, en passant, insufficient material, or the 50 move rule do not seem to apply.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The move is illegal because it is not specified which rook moves to c6 in the notation. You have to add the rank or file from which the rook comes from. Adding in extra "c", for the c-file rook, fixes the problem.

```
[FEN ""]
[startply "26"]

1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. Nd5 Nd4 4. Ne5 Ne4 5. Nb6 Nb3 6. Ng6 Ng3 7. axb3 axb6 8. hxg3 hxg6 9. Ra4 Rh5 10. Rf4 Rc5 11. Rf6 Rc3 12. Rh4 Ra5 13. Rc4 Rf5 14. Rcc6
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so easy when you know it...